# Дизайн Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, material-design, design, metro-framework

Всем привет, пишу курсач на C#, (тема АИС "Мебельный магазин", программа "построена" на контейнере MDI, кода мало, в основном все за счет "конструктора") в целом ничего не обычного, так вот хотелось бы хоть какой-то приятный вид придать, что-то в стиле Materia, Metro, Fluent. Нашел Telerik UI, но в случае его использования необходимо все заново делать да и с ним не особо склеилось, в процессе гугления ничего подходящего не нашел или плохо искал, в основном все про WPF. Может кто сталкивался с похожим вопросом?

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вся прелесть WinForms (и WinAPI) в том, что внешний вид приложения соответствует установленной теме операционной системы. То есть пользователь может менять стиль всех приложений в Windows единообразно, подгоняя сразу их все под свои предпочтения.

Comment: Т.е без вариантов натянуть какой-либо стиль?

Comment: Если вопросы о виндовой десктопной проге и стилях/кастомизации, то вам надо wpf, формы просто не предназначены дня этого.

Answer (score 1):

Если переопределить потом некоторые классы, то с помощью вот [этого](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin) можно будет достичь нужного эффекта. Пакет так же доступен через NuGet.

[image: изображение]

Comment: Кстати, это тоже пробовал, с ним скорее хуже чем без него.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот этот пакет https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialSkin.2/. Делал на его основе раньше тоже курсовые работы. Вполне можно настроить похожим на дизайн мобилок.

Полезные ссылки на видео с ютуба:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEtXGyn8OMA&t

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvL4bDZccJU&t

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX9E2azR1DY